# z-index issue with twitter bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, z-index

I'm using twitter bootstrap dropdown menu in a fixed navbar at the top of my page.

It all works fine but am having issues with the drop down menu items showing behind other page elements rather than in front of them.

If I have anything on the page with `position: relative` (like jquery ui accordion, or a google chart) then the drop down menu shows behind it.  Tried changing the `z-index` of the dd menu and of the nav-bar, but doesn't make any difference.

The only way I can get the menu to sit above the other content is to change the content to `position: fixed;` OR `z-index: -1;`  -but both of these solutions cause other problems.

Appreciate any help you can give me.

I think this is probably some standard issue with CSS positioning that I've misunderstood, so haven't posted any code, but can do if needed.

Thanks.

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149701/bootstrap-dropdowns-menus-appearing-behind-other-elements-ie7/36063349#36063349

Answer (score 61):

Just realized what's going on.

I had the navbar inside a header which was `position: fixed`;

Changed the `z-index` on the header and it's working now - guess I didn't look high enough up the containers to set the `z-index` initially !#@!?

Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar issue that turned out to caused by "overflow: hidden" on a parent div. The solution was easy for me since, after reviewing it, I determined that I didn't need the overflow: hidden anymore so I removed it.

Comment: @ScottForsyth-MVP I skimmed past your comment thinking.. overflow:hidden - that's not my issue - mine is all about z-index. So I went to the MDN page on stacking contexts (highly recommend) and went through my site meticulously setting positions and correct z-indices. Still the menu was being cut off. Then I noticed overflow:hidden in the css inspector and it reminded me of your comment - and that was it!

Comment: Although I have a slightly different structure in the DOM and elements, what made the solution for me in the end was changing the z-index of the element that contained the dropdown element(s). Thanks!

Comment: @ScottForsyth-MVP Thanks! your comment saved my live :D

Comment: I had overlay when dropdown is shown and dropdown was behind the overlay. Using the answer I gave my header `position: relative` and z-index that is more than z-index of overlay solved my issue.

Answer (score 16):

IE 7 on windows8 with bootstrap 3.0.0.

```
.navbar {
  position: static;
}
.navbar .nav > li {
  z-index: 1001;
}
```

fixed

Answer (score 10):

Ran into the same bug here. This worked for me.

```
.navbar {
    position: static;
}
```

By setting the position to static, it means the navbar will fall into the flow of the document as it normally would.

Comment: Worked for me, no side effects.

Answer (score 6):

This will fix it

```
.navbar .nav > li {
z-index: 10000;
}
```

Comment: This will cause problems with bootstrap modal dialogs, as modal-backdrop's z-index value is lower.

Answer (score 4):

In my case in addition to `z-index` I had to set `overflow: visible` in parents elements

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and after reading this topic, I've solved adding this to my CSS:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

because in my case, I'm using the fixed top menu.

Answer (score 2):

Solved by removing the `-webkit-transform` from the navbar:

`-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);`

pillaged from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12653766/391925

Answer (score 2):

Still the issue with Bootstrap v3, navbar and dropdown have same z-index ;-( I just increased .dropdown-menu z-index to 1001.

Comment: I just increased .dropdown-menu z-index to 1001. The solution is to increase this value. Sorry for my bad english ^^

Comment: ahh .. then I misunderstood you, sorry. You might consider a slight clarification in your answer (like you did in your comment :-)

Answer (score 2):

Just give

```
position: relative; 
z-index: 999;
```

to the navbar

Comment: This works for me but you don't need to set the z-index property to 999. You can set it to 2.

Answer (score 1):

This fixed it for me:

```
.navbar-wrapper {
  z-index: 11;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved this issue by removing `transform: translateY(50%);` property.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
.dropdown, .dropdown-menu {
  z-index:2;
}
.navbar {
  position: static;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, in my case because i forgot this in my NavBar style:
overflow: hidden;

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a situation where a button with a Bootstrap drop down was embedded in a DataTables row. In that instance, I had to remove `fixedColumns: true` in the settings because that was injecting a `position: sticky` into the element style.

Did not work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#order').DataTable({
            fixedColumns: true,
            fixedHeader: true, ...
```

Did work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $('#order').DataTable({
                fixedHeader: true, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party here but for anyone using the bootstrap `sticky-top` class beware that it's z-index is higher than what is defined for the dropdown so anything within it will bleed through the dropdown's menu.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/31747

This was my scenario and the other answers here that referenced `position: sticky` put me onto it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was caused because I had a CSS animation with `transform` operations applied to a parent `<div>`. I worked around the problem by moving the animation to a different element.