# Bootstrap dropdowns menus appearing behind other elements - IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-7

I'm using Bootstrap 2.3.1 http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/index.html

So I'm using their 'dropdown-menu' class to create some simple quick use dropdown menus, but for some reason on **IE7** they are appearing behind text and other elements on my site.

**Test Link:** http://leongaban.com/_projects/defakto/CDS/

I added z-index to my CSS, but still doesn't seem to do anything, please help!

```
.header .header-nav ul#nav-account ul.dropdown-menu,
.header .header-nav ul#nav-library ul.dropdown-menu {
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

IE9, Chrome, FF and other modern no headache browsers:
[image]

---

IE7 >:(
[image]

HTML

```
<div class="header-nav">

<ul id="nav-account" role="navigation" class="pull-right">

    <!-- Language Dropdown Button -->
    <li id="language-btn">
        <a href="#" id="drop1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">English</a>
        <img src="img/header-small-down-arrow.png" alt="grey triangle"/><!-- <span class="grey_triangle"></span>-->

        <!-- Language Dropdown Menu-->
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop1">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">English</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Spanish</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">German</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Japanese</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Chinese</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <!-- User Dropdown Button -->
    <li id="account-btn">
        <a href="#" id="drop2" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Logout</a>
        <img src="img/header-small-down-arrow.png" alt="grey triangle"/>
        <!-- <span class="grey_triangle"></span> -->

        <!-- User Dropdown Menu-->
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop2">
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="http://google.com">Logout</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#anotherAction">Account</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you try `$('.dropdown-menu').appendTo($("body"));`? If it's not going to work you can try another class instead .dropdown-menu but it is going to fix the issue, I guess.

Comment: Hmm just tried both those options, the jquery didn't do anything (but break the non-IE7 dropdowns) and I renamed .dropdown-menu to .dropdown-menu1 and still same issue :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make div go behind another div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561585/how-to-make-div-go-behind-another-div)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

**Its a [stacking context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1287439/ie7-z-index-layering-issues) issue!**

Even though you are using `z-index` on the dropdown, it is only relative to elements in the same stacking context. You need to add a `z-index` and a `position` to a parent element in order to get this to work. In this case I would recommend the `header-top` `div`

Comment: And thanks! I added position: relative; to some container divs and it fixed my problem :) IE7 & 8 can't die fast enough...

Comment: Thanks for the clue: Stacking.

If two elements are overlapping, put relative position on their parent.

Comment: I have that problem too, but I use both position and z-index and it still doesn't work

Comment: I added **style={{ zIndex:1020,position:'relative'}}** to the Immediate parent (CardHeader in my case) of my **React Material UI button** that triggers the Popper

Answer (score 28):

You can only use [`z-index`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index) on positioned elements (relative, fixed/absolute), so try adding:

```
.header .header-nav ul#nav-account ul.dropdown-menu,
.header .header-nav ul#nav-library ul.dropdown-menu {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10000;
}
```

Answer (score 18):

If increasing the z-index of the parent element(as mentioned in other answers) did not work for you, it could be that one of the parent elements has the following property:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Try changing it to:

```
overflow: visible;
```

and see if it works.

Comment: Oh man, I was stuck with this for couple of hours and saw your answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

Just make overflow as inherit or Visible.

it will solve the problem.

`overflow: visible !important;`

> It worked for me awesomely

Answer (score 2):

Check out the "[append-to vs. append-to-body vs. inline example](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown)" on the newest version of UI-Bootstrap lib.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing happen when using

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

On the parent element. Had to turn it off.

Answer (score -1):

it's resolved by adding in menu CSS.

```
position: relative;
z-index: 10000;
```