# How to make div go behind another div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the "box-left-mini" go in front of the `div` which is below.

```html
<div class="box-left-mini">
   this div is infront
    <div style="background-image:url(/images/hotcampaigns/campaign-sample.png);height:100px;width:100px;">
        this div is behind
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS for `box-left-mini` is:

```css
.box-left-mini {
    float:left;
    background-image:url(website-content/hotcampaign.png);
    width:292px;
    height:141px;
}
```

Comment: work with z-index to accomplish your desired outcome.

Comment: Make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The reason you're getting so many different answers is because you've not explained what you want to do exactly. All the answers you get with code will be programmatically correct, but it's all down to what you want to achieve

```css
.box-left-mini{
    float:left;
    background-image:url(website-content/hotcampaign.png);
    width:292px;
    height:141px;
}

.box-left-mini .front {
    display: block;
    z-index: 5;
    position: relative;
}
.box-left-mini .front span {
    background: #fff
}

.box-left-mini .behind_container {
    background-color: #ff0;
    position: relative;
    top: -18px;
}
.box-left-mini .behind {
    display: block;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-left-mini">
    <div class="front"><span>this is in front</span></div>
    <div class="behind_container">
        <div class="behind">behind</div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The jsfiddle is empty

Answer (score 15):

You need to add `z-index` to the divs, with a positive number for the top div and negative for the div below

```css
.one {   
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;
}

.two {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-999;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
   this div is infront
</div>

<div class="two">
   this div is behind
</div>
```

Comment: should be .two for the second selector in the css

Answer (score 7):

**To answer the question in a general manner:**

Using `z-index` will allow you to control this. see [z-index at csstricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/).

The element of higher `z-index` will be displayed on top of elements of lower `z-index`.

For instance, take the following HTML:

```
<div id="first">first</div>
<div id="second">second</div>
```

If I have the following CSS:

```
#first {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
}

#second {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

`#first` wil be on top of `#second`.

**But specifically in your case:**

The `div` element is a child of the `div` that you wish to put in front. This is not logically possible.

Answer (score 1):

One possible could be like this,

**HTML**

```
<div class="box-left-mini">
    <div class="front">this div is infront</div>
    <div class="behind">
        this div is behind
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box-left-mini{
float:left;
background-image:url(website-content/hotcampaign.png);
width:292px;
height:141px;
}
.front{
    background-color:lightgreen;
}
.behind{
    background-color:grey;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MgtWS/

But it really depends on the layout of your div elements i.e. if they are floating, or absolute positioned etc.

Answer (score -1):

Container can not come front to inner container. but try this below :

### Css :

```
.container { position:relative; }
    .div1 { width:100px; height:100px; background:#9C3; position:absolute; 
            z-index:1000; left:50px; top:50px; }
    .div2 { width:200px; height:200px; background:#900; }
```

### HTML :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">
       Div1 content here .........
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
       Div2 contenet here .........
    </div>
</div>
```