# div's appearing behind each other

Tags: html, css

I have problems with my `div`'s placing behind/on top of each other.

```css
td {
    width: 14.28%;
    height: 16.6%;
    position: relative;
    }

.details {
    position: absolute; 
    display: none;
    background-color: gray;
    overflow: visible;
    border: 2px solid black;
    } 

div:hover > .details {display: block;}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td *ngFor="let cell of ukeEn()">
                {{cell.text}}
                <div class="outer" *ngIf="datoerContains(cell) != null">
                  <div class="circle" *ngFor="let circle of datoerContains(cell)"></div>
                  <div class="details" *ngFor="let circle of datoerContains(cell)"> 
                    {{circle.skole}} <br>
                    {{circle.kommentar}} <br>
                    SFO: {{circle.sfodag}}
                  </div>

                </div>
            </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The problem is with the `details` class. Using the `*ngFor`, several `div`'s are created here - but you can only see one of them appearing as the other ones are "hiding" behind.

Any ideas? I was going to test two ways; beside each other, and below each other.
I would like to avoid removing `absolute` on the `.details` as it's used for another purpose.

Comment: So why exactly is .details positioned abso lutely?

Comment: You need to set positioning (`left`, `top`, etc) on `.details` if you're going to keep it absolute positioned.

Comment: tried `display: inline-block;´ ?

Comment: @FabianSchultz Because the div is bigger than the td, and with absolute I avoid expansion of the td (which the td would do to fit the div).

Comment: @J.Titus I have tried, it does not work

Comment: @weinde Tried that too, no success

Comment: to which element did you try aplying the display: inline-block; to?

Comment: @weinde the bottom one, I changed from block to inline-block

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make div go behind another div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19561585/how-to-make-div-go-behind-another-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to find a solution by playing around myself.
I removed `position` from both `td` and `.details`, and added `position: absolute` for `.outer`. Then they placed perfectly below each other.
To get them place beside each other, I just added `float: left` to `details`.

```
td {
    width: 14.28%;
    height: 16.6%;
    }

.outer {
    position: absolute
}

.details {
    display: none;
    background-color: gray;
    overflow: visible;
    border: 2px solid black;
    float: left;
    }
```