# Bootstrap navbar dropdown hidden behind bootstrap slider

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My dropdown menu made using bootstrap is hiding behind the slider that I made. I want it to show in front.

I have tried using:

```
z-index
overflow:visible
position:relative
```

according to the various solutions posted online under a similar problem. I have found no success with any of the solutions I tried.

I have a JSFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/8wq0ptrw/

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149701/bootstrap-dropdowns-menus-appearing-behind-other-elements-ie7

"if elements are not part of the same stack, `z-index` will not work unless their have a `position` property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the overflow:hidden from your nav-bar class. I hope this will help you.

```
.nav-bar {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see it by removing `display: none;` from  `.navbar` and `.collapse`.

I believe bootstrap provides a hamburger menu icon that you need to implement where you click it to remove the `display: none;` on these elements and show the the dropdown menu.