# Bootstrap Dropdown Falling Behind other Elements

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal

I'm having this same issue in all browsers in **Mobile View** only: 
[Bootstrap dropdowns menus appearing behind other elements - IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149701/bootstrap-dropdowns-menus-appearing-behind-other-elements-ie7)

But I tried the resolutions there and it's not working when I upload the files.  Weird thing is when I tried it in Chrome's Inspect field, it does work (the z-index and position:relative;)

Additionally, it's not a problem on the Home Page, only on the subpages.  Any help is appreciated. More HTML and CSS on my GitHub (for this page: [Bootstrap Dropdown Falling Behind other Elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50417141/bootstrap-dropdown-falling-behind-other-elements?noredirect=1#comment87850327_50417141))

I'm guessing it's inheriting from somewhere else, but no idea where.  [image: Example DropDown Issue]

```
    .yamm .nav, .yamm .collapse, .yamm .dropup, .yamm .dropdown {
    position: static;
}
.yamm .container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10000!important;
}
.yamm .dropdown-menu {
    left: auto;
}
.yamm .yamm-content {
    padding: 20px 30px;
}
.yamm .dropdown.yamm-fw .dropdown-menu {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you share code?

Comment: Just updated the code I believe it should be pulling from. Thank you!

Comment: If you share HTML & CSS code We can test it here and find out the solution

Comment: The HTML and style.css can be found at my GitHub (it's so long didn't want to convolute the question): https://github.com/allylarson/TheBMan