# React Native <View> to front of UI

Tags: reactjs, react-native, drop-down-menu, dropdown, overlay

I have a View component I'd like to bring to the foreground in my React Native App.

The component I'm trying to build is a "Select" input similar to the Web, where the dropdown of options will overlay on any other components underneath it, positioning will be absolute and underneath the select..

Similar to [this w3schools select.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bH7S.png)

I've attempted zIndexing and nothing will work properly.

[Here is the current issue I have.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIMgr.png)

The structure is

```
<Container>
    <AnotherContainer>
      <Select Component>
    <Buttons>
```

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: Does the answer from this help at all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149701/bootstrap-dropdowns-menus-appearing-behind-other-elements-ie7