# Twitter Bootstrap navbar dropdown goes under slider image

Tags: css, ipad, twitter-bootstrap-3, z-index, navbar

I have a navbar build with Twitter Bootstrap 3.1.1. When on an iPhone or iPad the dropdown menu hides behind the slider image. It has a position absolute and a z-index of 1000.

When on a desktop it goes well, it goes over de slider images.

If you go to http://sitegeregeld.nl/. You see that the dropdown menu disappears behind the slider on the homepage on an iPad and iPhone. I don't see a sollution.

What goes wrong?

Comment: What goes wrong ? Something... probably.

Comment: More seriously, could you provide us some code, a working fiddle, an example or a usable link ? We need a little bit of material to answer you.

Comment: @Kaj can you provide an example of the issue. may be through http://www.bootply.com/new or http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I did put in some extra info in the text.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem(only hiding behind content on ipad), and this solved it:

```
.navbar {
  position: static;
}
.navbar .nav > li {
  z-index: 1001;
}
```

I'm using a bootstrap/wordpress framework that has it's own css style sheet that sets the navbar to position: relative.

found answer here: [z-index issue with twitter bootstrap dropdown menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916326/z-index-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-menu)