# Bootstrap dropdown menu hidden behind other elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916326/z-index-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-menu) . But the solutions there does not work for my issue. And that discussion has been closed for further suggestions.
Unfortunately I can't show my code exactly as it is on jsfiddle. However the issue is something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hvx4zres/). When trying to expand the dropdown inside first panel section, the dropdown hidden behind other elements.
I've spent hours trying different suggestions concerning "stacking context", "position", and "z-index".
I would really appreciate if anyone could point me to any resources that could help.

```
<div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <span data-bind="label">Select One</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>

                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another item</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">This is a longer item that will not fit properly</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149701/bootstrap-dropdowns-menus-appearing-behind-other-elements-ie7/36063349#36063349

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have two options. You can make the container's overflow expand to fit the content by setting 'overflow: auto' to the parent's css.

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hvx4zres/3/)**

```
.panel-body { /* parent container of the menu */
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Or you could do something functionally with JavaScript to handle the menu placement. This option is a little bit 'hacky' and would require further improvements. You would need to improve it to handle multiple menus open at once on the same page, and you would need to improve how it selects the menu. You might also want to add scroll support to move the menu with its target element unless that's not an issue. Here's the fiddle:

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hvx4zres/2/)**

```
(function() {
  // hold onto the drop down menu                                             
  var dropdownMenu;

  // and when you show it, move it to the body                                     
  $(window).on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e) {

    // grab the menu        
    dropdownMenu = $(e.target).find('.dropdown-menu');

    // detach it and append it to the body
    $('body').append(dropdownMenu.detach());   

    // grab the new offset position
    var eOffset = $(e.target).offset();

    // make sure to place it where it would normally go (this could be improved)
    dropdownMenu.css({
        'display': 'block',
        'top': eOffset.top + $(e.target).outerHeight(),
        'left': eOffset.left
    });                                                
  });

  // and when you hide it, reattach the drop down, and hide it normally                                                   
  $(window).on('hide.bs.dropdown', function(e) {        
    $(e.target).append(dropdownMenu.detach());        
    dropdownMenu.hide();                              
  });                                                   
})();
```

There is probably a better way to do this, but the concept is to move the menu from the confines of the parent element to the body. When you're relying on the html data-attributes to setup the menu, you'll have trouble doing this, but that is where the second solution I reference becomes useful.

Sadly I would have suggested looking into the 'Via Javascript' options that bootstrap provides, but apparently they don't have the option to set the target append element. It would have been nice to have an option to append the menu on to whichever element you want like most of their other items: **[Bootstrap Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-usage)**

---

**EDIT**

As @Andrea Pizzirani mentioned, you could try removing the css for the menu absolute positioning, but I wouldn't recommend it! That will mess up all other instances of the menu unless you add other css to restrict scope of the change. Also, if you want the menu positioned under the button, you'll have to redo CSS that bootstrap already had in place.

Still, if it works, and you're not worried about messing up all other menus, it may be the solution you were looking for. Heres a fiddle demonstrating the solution:

**[FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/hvx4zres/4/)**

```
dropdown-menu {}
```

---

**EDIT**
I finally found where I originally found this solution. Gotta give credit where [credit is due!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27711138/2041091)

Comment: I can't see the entire dropdown in your first fiddle (Chrome v. 45), can you? However the second solution with JS is working. Thank you very much for the time and effort.

Comment: Yeah, the first solution only allows the parent container to expand so that you can scroll to see the rest of the dropdown. But I'm glad the JS version works for you!

Comment: The js version works great in bootstrap 4! The menu even scrolls with the container. Thanks. This was driving me crazy - this is the only real solution when you have a table cell with a popup menu.

Comment: I may have spoken too soon - this is not a panacea by any means. Since it removes the menu from its normal document flow, any kind of jQuery plugin that may depend on that structure will be broken.

Comment: @BrucePierson if you come up with a better solution, let me know! I only posted an answer to this because the problem was interesting. Flow was the problem from the beginning, so noting that there are side effects manipulating the flow is a very apt observation. Thank you for noting that it will very likely impact other jQuery plugins depending on the dropdown menu's flow.

Comment: @Jonathan nothing yet - Bootstrap has it marked as a will not fix because it's really a popper.js problem. I've looked at some of the issues over there but can't find an answer for a popup menu in a table cell. By the way, it only affects tables that are in a div with the `table-responsive` class. If you remove this, it works, but of course then the tables overflow the viewport.

Comment: This was a huge help, but I modified it to place the menu back at it's source row, which allows custom jQuery to function properly (because the menu still exists at its initial parent element hierarchy. My use case was a jQuery Datatable with frozen columns. We had a bootstrap 4 dropdown-menu embedded in a cell of that table. The menu was appearing behind the hidden columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove **position: absolute;** from:

```
dropdown-menu {}
```

and place the menu under the button by css.

Answer (score 0):

Modification of Jonathan's answer above, which was a huge help, but I modified it to place the menu back at it's source row, which allows custom jQuery to function properly (because the menu still exists at its initial parent element hierarchy. My use case was a jQuery DataTable with frozen columns. We had a bootstrap 4 "Action" dropdown-menu embedded in a cell of that table. The menu was appearing behind the hidden columns. This function allowed it be copied and pasted above the fixed columns where users can actually interact with it.

```
function BringActionMenuToForeground() {
    var dropdownMenu;

    /// When you show the menu, remove it from its current row and place it right back. This puts it on top of the DOM.
    $(window).on('show.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
        /// grab the menu
        dropdownMenu = $(e.target).find('.dropdown-menu');
        /// get the row where the menu appers.
        var menuRow = $(dropdownMenu).closest("tr");
        /// detach it and append it right back to the row from which it was taken.
        $(menuRow).append(dropdownMenu.detach());

        /// grab the new offset position
        var eOffset = $(e.target).offset();

        /// make sure to place it where it would normally go (this could be improved)
        dropdownMenu.css({
            'display': 'block',
            'top': eOffset.top + $(e.target).outerHeight(),
            'left': eOffset.left
        });
    });

    /// and when you hide it, reattach the drop down, and hide it normally                                                   
    $(window).on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
        $(e.target).append(dropdownMenu.detach());
        dropdownMenu.hide();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional class on your HTML and use the below codepen reference code.

```
check here: https://codepen.io/qpqinc/pen/yLyPVMJ


<div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
              Dropdown
              <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
              <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>


$(function() {
  //add BT DD show event
  $(".dropdown").on("show.bs.dropdown", function() {
    var $btnDropDown = $(this).find(".dropdown-toggle");
    var $listHolder = $(this).find(".dropdown-menu");
    //reset position property for DD container
    $(this).css("position", "static");
    $listHolder.css({
      "top": ($btnDropDown.offset().top + $btnDropDown.outerHeight(true)) + "px",
      "left": $btnDropDown.offset().left + "px"
    });
    $listHolder.data("open", true);
  });
  //add BT DD hide event
  $(".dropdown").on("hidden.bs.dropdown", function() {
    var $listHolder = $(this).find(".dropdown-menu");
    $listHolder.data("open", false);
  });
  //add on scroll for table holder
  $(".ak-holder").scroll(function() {
    var $ddHolder = $(this).find(".dropdown")
    var $btnDropDown = $(this).find(".dropdown-toggle");
    var $listHolder = $(this).find(".dropdown-menu");
    if ($listHolder.data("open")) {
      $listHolder.css({
        "top": ($btnDropDown.offset().top + $btnDropDown.outerHeight(true)) + "px",
        "left": $btnDropDown.offset().left + "px"
      });
      $ddHolder.toggleClass("open", ($btnDropDown.offset().left > $(this).offset().left))
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33509239)

Comment: @AaronMeese thanks for the comment, I just copied core part of logic that is we just have to top of button need to add div with class <div class="dropdown"> then related jquery. that's it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help someone, I spent hours on this:

[image]

And for me this issue was from this style on a parent div:

`backdrop-filter: blur(50px);`

Just had to remove it to get the dropdown-menu not being hidden over some  elements of the page!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to add only:

```
.panel.panel-default{
      overflow: inherit !important;
    }
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/7xvwk9fm/2/)**