# Bootstrap dropdown-menu z-index on dynamically generated containers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 dropdown-menu inside a dynamically generated container. The dropdown-menu appears behind the newly generated elements. See image reference.

[image]

container item `position: relative; z-index: 1;`
dropdown-menu `position: absolute; z-index: 10000;`

I also did test btn-group with a higher z-index and it did not work.

Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sGem8/

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for it. We can't say anything by just looking at the image..

Comment: Will do. Will post it in a moment. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Hi @VishalKhode, here is the working fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/sGem8/

Comment: Now I know why this didn't work. Tried taking out the z-index property but still. This div is contained by jQueryUI draggable property and forces the div to get a z-index of 0. I don't want to hack it. It may destroy some properties linked to it. I just repositioned the button somewhere else. So much for this headache. Thanks again!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28212815/1166597

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add z-index property.. Simply remove it and it will work.. 
i.e.

```
#container > li {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #ecf0f1;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sGem8/2/)**

Comment: Thanks Vishal, I really thought just now that z-index overrides the property of the dropdown-menu.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue.
Inside the main container which had all the nav-items, I had every outermost div items as `position: relative`
Only the dropdown menu had `position: absolute`

To make the dropdown appear above all items, add

```
.dropdown{
position: absolute;
z-index : 999; //some high value
}
```

and other items in the container have

```
.outer-divs{
position: relative;  
z-index: 1; //some low value
}
```

If you still find your dropdown to behave not as expected,
try setting the div item that opens the dropdown when clicked to

```
.dropdown-container{
position  :static;
}
```

Most people will find the last trick to be the most valuable.
Hope this helps.

Comment: The last item did it for me after trying everything else for hours. Should this be its own answer?

Answer (score 1):

Modify the below css in your styles

```
#container > li {
 display: block;
 border-radius: 3px;
 position: relative;
 /* z-index: 0; */
 padding: 15px;
 background: #ecf0f1;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```